# Why is the Integral with Abs showing imaginary unit as an output?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

Both the following expressions, when evaluated and looking at them, will give in the output the imaginary unit even if I ask for the `Abs`. However, when plotting the final function I get what I want. So, what I don't understand is the presence of `I` after `Abs`

```
IntegrandON = 
 Simplify[Abs[
     1 - (1 - I)/2*(beta/2)^(0.5)*Cosh[(1 - I)*z*(beta/2)^(0.5)]/(Sinh[(1 - I)/2*(beta/2)^(0.5)])]
    // ComplexExpand, beta > 0]^2;

IntegralExact = FullSimplify[Integrate[IntegrandON, {z, -0.5, 0.5}]]

exact = 0.05379*beta/IntegralExact;

LogLogPlot[{exact}, {beta, 1, 100000}]
```

Comment: There is no `Abs` after `ComplexExpand`, which might not be a particularly safe transformation.  However, as Igor Rivin points out, the imaginary parts cancel out, save for rounding error.

Answer (score 2):

The integral can be expressed as some special function, which is then evaluated at the endpoints. The value of said special function is complex in general, but happens to be real in your case. However, since the value is *approximate*, there will be small complex noise, which you can get rid of with `Chop[]` if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an exact expression use `Sqrt[expr]` or `expr^(1/2)` rather than `expr^(0.5)`

```
IntegrandON = 
  Simplify[Abs[
      1 - (1 - I)/2*(beta/2)^(1/2)*
        Cosh[(1 - I)*z*(beta/2)^(1/2)]/(Sinh[(1 - I)/2*(beta/2)^(1/2)])] // 
     ComplexExpand, beta > 0]^2;
```

Similarly, for an exact expression the bounds of the integration must be exact

```
IntegralExact = Simplify[Integrate[IntegrandON, {z, -1/2, 1/2}]]

(*  -1 + (Sqrt[beta]*
        (Sin[Sqrt[beta]/Sqrt[2]] + 
           Sinh[Sqrt[beta]/Sqrt[2]]))/
     (2*Sqrt[2]*
        (-Cos[Sqrt[beta]/Sqrt[2]] + 
           Cosh[Sqrt[beta]/Sqrt[2]]))  *)

exact = 0.05379*beta/IntegralExact;

Minimize[{exact, 1 < beta < 100}, beta]

(*  {1.81751, {beta -> 46.4348}}  *)

LogLogPlot[exact, {beta, 1, 100000}]
```

[image]